# Как создать таймер на записи из таблицы, по истечению времени которые переносились в другие таблицы? Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

Не знаю, возможно ли создать такую функцию, но в голове вертится. Есть три таблицы в базе данных FireBase. 1 таблица это список тех книг, который взял пользователь на прочтение. 2 таблица, это книги, срок которых начинает истекать. 3 таблица, книги, срок хранения которых истек и их следует сдать обратно в библиотеку. По логике, должна быть шкала в 100%. 1 таблица хранит в себе 50%, 2 таблица следующие 50%. когда дойдёт до 100%, то книга переходит в 3 таблицу. например по календарю. если я возьму книгу 1 марта, а должна буду вернуть ее 10 марта, то 5 числа книга в идеале должна перейти во 2 таблицу, то есть в таблицу, время которой истекает. а после 10 марта, в 3 таблицу, когда время истекло и следует ее вернуть. Работа заключается в android studio. есть база, которая хранит в себе просто книги, и возможность добавлять книги. так же есть авторизация. возможно ли осуществить то, что я описала выше?..

Comment: А обязательно иметь столько таблиц? Почему в таблице не хранить одно доп. поле в котором будет дата когда книгу нужно вернуть? А выборку по истекшим и тд делать уже запросом?

Comment: По заданию нужно создать 3 страницы в мобильном приложении, в которой: 1 страница имеет зеленые границы с наименованием книги, 2 страница с желтым сочетанием и 3 страница с красным, поэтому наверное и нужны 3 таблицы для этой реализации?

Comment: Таблица != view в андроиде. Значит вам достаточно хранить дату. В параметрах же хранить за сколько дней до сдачи книги она должна быть во 2 вкладке и после прохождения даты сдачи уже в 3.

Comment: Не совсем поняла. Как в android studio это осуществить? В каком классе? Создала добавление даты, и теперь она есть в базе данных вместе с названием книги и автором книги. А дальше что делать с ней